# Swift - Adjust Large Title in Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, titlebar, ui-design

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Pn5.png)

```
 self.titleLabel.title = (NSLocalizedString("Discover", comment: "").localized(lang))
```

I tried to move the Discover Title to the same line that these three button by adding this one but it not worked

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(.init(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

what is the best way to make the large title in the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use large title (Don't check Prefers Large Titles)

You can set the title font.

StoryBoard -> NavigationController -> Title -> Title Text Attributes, change Title Font Size

If you want to place the title on the left side of the navigation bar, Use leftBarButtonItem

Try this!

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "YourTitle"
titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        
let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: titleLabel)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```